# Random Value GeoNode on Mesh Line Node parameters

Tags: geometry-nodes

Im trying to instance a mesh line on each vert of a grid.

But id like to randomize the length or count(resolution?) attribute of each individual mesh line (because ill instance a stack of objects on each mesh line point). The randomize node works with scale/position on a transform node in the tree. But Id really like to use it on the count, end point vector, or resolution of the specific mesh line node. I kinda got a noise node to work but its randomizing the end point of all mesh lines instances by the same amount. anything else with a random value node will create a red line inbetween the sockets. So is this possible?

[image]

Comment: this is not possible with instancing because instances cannot be changed as you want it (that's what's the diamonds and (filled)circles are for, you cannot connect those). But i am convinced it is possible with GN with clever math and some realize instances and lots of thinking ;) or short: you cannot change instances per instance. Just afterwards ...(after the instance on points)

Comment: @Chris just stomped on another one of my answers ;) .. As he says, the key is: use Curve Lines instead of Mesh Lines, because they can be resampled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, i figured it out how you can do it:

[image]

result:

[image]

The main idea was: just move the upper vertices of the curves randomly by noise, then subdivide the curves depending on their height. That's it.

Comment: thanks! im not sure if ive got it working though. still trying to wrap my head around it. The curve node on the right, which i think youve renamed?, is that Resample Curve? if it is, mine doesnt have a selection socket. maybe a different blender version?

also, im working in smaller units, mm, so if i wanted to scale this down, which nodes should i and should i not touch to avoid breaking it. I tried a bit and at a certain size it seems a lot of it gets clamped or something.

Comment: yes, i am working on 3.1. And yes, it is a resample curve node. Did you set it to length? that's important. And yes, you should have written that in your question if you use a specific blender version, so i was assuming you used the newest.

Comment: sorry, i am using 3.0, sometimes i forget how many more features are in alpha versions. i did set it to length. Switching to alpha and fixing another node make the version you made work great. Now im just trying to figure out a way to shrink it to a smaller scale. Im essentially trying to have a true-to-scale stack of poker chips. changing some of the nodes past a certain point seems to break it. While the smallest i can make it without breaking, each column height will jump in segments of what look like whole grid units, instead of smaller increments. https://i.imgur.com/bCh0fdy.jpg